# Bash script not giving desired output

Tags: html, regex, bash

My bash script below is not giving the desired output in the form of HTML code.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Usage : flog LOGFILE"
exit 1
fi

logfile=$1
sed -i 's/invalid/<UNKNOWN>/g' $logfile
grep "Failed password for" $logfile | cut -d" " -f4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2 > templog
sed -i 's/</\$lt;/g;s/>/\&gt;/g;s/^/<br \/>/g;' templog

echo "<html>" > flog.html
echo "<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts Report as of `date` </h1>" >> flog.html
cat templog >> flog.html
echo "/body" >> flog.html
echo "</html>" >> flog.html
cat flog.html
```

The output it's giving looks like this...

```
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts Report as of Fri Jan 26 19:49:49 MST 2018 </h1>
<br />   1888 localhost
<br />      1 08:59:54
<br />      1 09:11:49
<br />      1 09:11:54
<br />      1 09:11:58
<br />      1 09:12:03
<br />      1 09:12:09
<br />      1 09:12:14
<br />      1 09:12:24
</body>
</html>
```

when I need the output to look like this:

```
<html>
<body><h1>Failed Login Attempts Report as of Thu Dec 25 07:00:00 MST 2014</h1>
<br /> 1,325 &lt;UNKNOWN&gt;
<br /> 505 root
<br /> 17 adm
<br /> 16 ftp
<br /> 10 apache
<br /> 10 mail
<br /> 2 backuppc
<br /> 2 games
<br /> 2 news
<br /> 2 squid
<br /> 1 bin
<br /> 1 nobody
<br /> 1 operator
<br /> 1 smmsp
<br /> 1 sshd</body> </html>
```

Can anyone help me? What do I need to change? I know that this is a probably a poorly formed question, but I'm giving this a shot.

Comment: What does your log file contain?

Comment: <br />   1888 localhost
<br />      1 08:59:54
<br />      1 09:11:49
<br />      1 09:11:54
<br />      1 09:11:58
<br />      1 09:12:03
<br />      1 09:12:09
<br />      1 09:12:14
<br />      1 09:12:24

Comment: Looks like that's a problem haha

Comment: How do I make it look like the desired output?

Comment: You have to [edit] the question and add your input there, it's impossible to tell what's going on otherwise.

Comment: I very much doubt your logfile contains what you pasted in the comment above, if it produces the output you gave in your question.

Comment: Post your actual input file so we can provide a better solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your section:

```
logfile=$1
sed 's/invalid/<UNKNOWN>/g' $logfile
grep "Failed password for" $logfile | cut -d" " -f4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2 > templog
sed 's/</\$lt;/g;s/>/\&gt;/g;s/^/<br \/>/g;' templog
```

First of all: use quotes. This may not be the source of your current problem, but it will most probably give problems in the future. So:

```
logfile="$1"
```

The main issue of your question is probably the `cut -d" " -f4`, and more specifically the `4`. This selects the 4th field, which is (apparently) the time. I could suggest that it might be `5`, but I don't know what your input looks like.It is most certainly not what you answered in the comments.

So, it would suggest:

```
uidfield=5
logfile="$1"
sed -i 's/invalid/<UNKNOWN>/g' "$logfile" |
  grep "Failed password for" |
  cut -d" " -f$uidfield |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  sort -n |
  sed -i 's/</\&lt;/g;s/>/\&gt;/g;s/^/<br \/>/g;' > templog
```

and play with the `uidfield=5` until you get the right field.

Another remark: in `s/^/<br \/>/g`, the `g` is a bit overdone, because there is only one start of line per line.

Comment: What would you suggest for the g part?

Comment: `g` means global in the line. For example: `s/i/o/g` will substitute all i's into o's. `s/i/o/` will substitute only the first i in the line by an o. So, in this case, `s/^/<br \/>/' should be sufficient.

Comment: sed is also a file editor.
sed -i actually edits the file.

Comment: right. I was too quick with that. Removed the remark about sed.